# combine layers from different neural networks

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tensorflow to train two instances of the same neural network with two different datasets. the network itself is quite simple with an input and output layer and 6 hidden layers (each layer is a 20 meurons followed by a non-linear activation function).

I can train the network with two different datasets and that is fine. Now, what i want to do is basically create a new network which is a combination of these two trained networks. In particular, I want the input and the first 3 layers to be from one of the trained network and the last 3 layers and the output layer to be from the other network. I am very new to tensorflow and have not found a way to do this. Can someone point me to the API or some way to do this sort of hybrid networks?

Answer (score 0):

Constructing your network with Keras will make this easy; see [the keras documentation](https://keras.io/) for how to reuse layers across networks.

Answer (score 0):

You might be asking about multitask learning aspect,well it can be simplified by seperating the weight matrix of each individual variables trained with different datasets and sum there weight layers individually to a sharable_weight_layer variable after a, b trained networks and finally evaluate your model as summed network in multitasking method.

Comment: An example would help to convey your message. So would punctuation.